# Why when the implication is false, its converse is also false in this example?

Tags: implicit-function-theorem

As we all know:

> To prove that an implication is true,just prove that its converse is false.

For example,from elementary calculus we know that the assertion
"If a function is continuous, then it is differentiable"
is false. This allows us to reach at the correct conclusion that its converse,
"If a function is differentiable, then it is continuous"
is true, as indeed it is.

But wait a minute! The implication"
If a function is differentiable, then it is not continuous"
is completely false. So we could conclude that its converse 
"If a function is not continuous, then it is differentiable"
should be true, but in fact the converse is also completely false!

So something has gone wrong here. But where?

Comment: What you are claiming is not true.  Sometimes both proposition and converse are true.  Sometimes both are false.

Comment: It is not true you can prove an implication is true by proving its converse is false.  You could prove its negation is false (that's the contradiction approach).  But the converse is just something else.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I can't understand.Because (P IMPLIES Q) OR (Q IMPLIES P) is always true,so I think we can prove an implication is true by proving its converse is false

Comment: P IMPLIES Q is an implication,its converse is Q IMPLIES P

Comment: It is clearly not the case the one of $P \implies Q$ or $Q\implies P$ must be true.   "If $p$ is a prime number then $p$ is greater than $100$" say.  Or "If a person is over $6$ feet tall then that person is a doctor."

Comment: @lulu But how to explain that " (P IMPLIES Q) OR (Q IMPLIES P) " is always true?As it is always true,we could say that there must be one is true and the other is false

Comment: You keep saying that, but as I have pointed out it is not true.  I have given you two clear counterexamples.  Please study those counterexamples and persuade yourself that what you are saying simply is not true.

Comment: @lulu : It is logically correct to say that either $p \implies q$ or $q \implies p$.  Your counter-example is not quite correct because it has the (different) form [$p(x)\implies q(x)$ for all $x$] or [$q(x) \implies p(x)$ for all $x$].  $$(p\implies q) Or  (q \implies p) = ((not p) OR q) or  ((not q) OR p) = TRUE$$

Comment: @lulu I think the difference that is showing up is that implies is taken to be universally quantified in math, but as a Boolean expression, a conditional or its converse is true.

Comment: @lulu : It may help to replace $x$ with $25$ in your statement:  One of  "If 25 is prime then 25 is greater than 100" or "If 25 is greater than 100 then 25 is prime" is indeed true.

Comment: @Michael  I take your point, but the examples used by the OP are of the general sort, not the particular.  That is the OP believes that one of the statements "a function is differentiable implies it is not continuous" or "a function which is not continuous must be differentiable" has to hold generally.

Comment: @lulu I agree.  I think the explanation of that distinction  would clarify/answer the OP's question.

Comment: In the OP statement, the $x$ is a function $f$. So that statement is implictly saying $\forall f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is logically correct to say that 
$$ (p \implies q)\quad OR \quad (q \implies p)$$
It is also logically correct to say
$$ [(p(x)\implies q(x))\quad OR \quad (q(x) \implies p(x))] \quad \forall x \in X$$
However, it is not logically correct to say that 
$$ [(p(x)\implies q(x)) \quad \forall x \in X] \quad OR \quad [(q(x)\implies p(x)) \quad \forall x \in X] $$

Your statement about differentiable functions has the latter form (and is not correct):

$$[(\mbox{$f$ differentiable} \implies \mbox{$f$ not continuous})\forall f \in F]\quad OR \quad [(\mbox{$f$ not continuous} \implies \mbox{$f$ differentiable})\forall f \in F]$$
where $F$ is the set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  On the other hand, if we take any *specific* function $f \in F$, such as $f(t) =e^t$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, then we indeed get a correct statement: 
$$(\mbox{$e^t$ differentiable} \implies \mbox{$e^t$ not continuous})\quad OR \quad (\mbox{$e^t$ not continuous} \implies \mbox{$e^t$ differentiable})$$ and indeed the latter is true.

---

Aside: Proof of the more general logical statement: For any three propositions $p,q,r$ we have
$$ (p\implies q) \quad OR \quad (q \implies r)$$

Proof: 
\begin{align}
(p\implies q) \quad OR (q \implies r) &= (\lnot p \quad OR \quad q) \quad OR \quad (\lnot q \quad OR \quad r)\\
&= (\lnot p) \quad OR\quad  (q) \quad OR \quad (\lnot q) \quad  OR\quad  r\\
&= True
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Your claim isn't exactly correct, it usually known this way, if you want to prove $p\implies q$ (i.e. if $p$ then $q$) you can prove that $\lnot q \implies \lnot p$ (i.e. if $q$ is false then $p$ is false), they are both the same thing.

Comment: But how to explain that " (P IMPLIES Q) OR (Q IMPLIES P) " is always true?As it is always true,we could say that there must be one is true and the other is false.

Comment: I mean either (P IMPLIES Q)  is true while (Q IMPLIES P)  is false or (Q IMPLIES P)  is true while (P IMPLIES Q) is false

Comment: @Chor : You are correct that $p \implies q$ or $q \implies p$.  Sometimes both of them are true (take $p=q=\{1+1=2\}$ as an example).

Comment: @Michael So there is totally 3 conditions? Both are true or one is true and the other is false.

Comment: Note:   $\lnot q \implies \lnot p$ is called the *contrapositive* of $p\implies q$

Comment: @Chor : Yes, those are the three options.

Comment: @Chor : By the way: I don't think I have _ever_ used the fact $p\implies q$ or $q \implies p$ in any real-life problem.  But I have often used the fact that $p \implies q$ is equivalent to $(not q)\implies (not p)$.

Comment: @Michael Sure,if p⟹q  is true.then (notq)⟹(notp) must be true.

Comment: @Michael but how about (A person is fat $\implies$ he is tall) and (A person is tall $\implies$ he is fat) are both wrong, aren't they?

Comment: It depends on if you are saying "$[\forall x(\mbox{person(x) is fat $\implies \mbox{person(x)}$ is tall})]$ or $[\forall x(\mbox{person(x) is tall $\implies \mbox{person(x)}$ is fat})]$" versus "[Bill is fat implies Bill is tall] or [Bill is tall implies Bill is fat]." See my answer. Note that $p\implies q$ is true whenever $q$ is true, it is also true whenever $p$ is false.